# How to change URL of browser window from within frameset frame?

Tags: html, frames, frameset, html-frames

I have an html document using frames. This is the code:

```
<frameset cols="10%,*" border="0">
<frame src="left_page.html">
<frameset rows="50%,50%" border="0">
</frameset>
</frameset>
```

Then in left_page.html, this is my code:

```
<form action="http:www.google.com">
<input type="submit" value="GotoGoogle" />
</form>
```

The problem is, when I click the button, it loads google.com in the left frame, not the entire screen. How can I get the web page to display on the entire screen and not just the left side frame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the target frame (_top is the full page)

```
<form action="http:www.google.com" target="_top">
<input type="submit" value="GotoGoogle" />
</form>
```

Comment: code only answers aren't answers IMO - flesh it out and explain so OP understands the problem/solution